# What happens to the positional encodings in the output of of the Transformer model?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, artificial-intelligence, transformer-model

I've been learning about the [new popular Transformer model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762), which can be used for sequence-to-sequence language applications. I am considering an application of time-series modeling, which is not necessarily language modeling. Thus I am modeling where the output layer maybe is not a probability, but could perhaps be a prediction of the next value of the time series.

If I consider the original language model presented in the paper (see Figure 1), we notice that positional encodings are applied to the embedded input data, however there is no indication of a position in the output. The output simply gives probabilities for value at the "next" time step. To me it seems like something is being lost here. The output assumes an iterative process, where the "next" output is just next because it is next. However in the input we feel the need to insert some positional information with the positional encodings. I would think we should also be interested in the positional encodings of the output as well. Is there a way to recover them?

This problem becomes more pronounced if we consider non-uniformly sampled time series data. This is really what I am interested in. It would be interesting to use non-uniformly sampled time series as input and predict the "next" value of the time series, where we also get the time position of that prediction. This comes down to somehow recovering the positional information from that output value. Since the positional encoding of the input is added to the input, it is not trivial how to extract this positional information from the output, perhaps it should be called "positional decoding".

To sumarize, my question is, what happens to the positional information in the output? Is it still there but I am just missing it? Also, does anyone see a straightforward way of recovering this data if not immediately available by the model?

Thanks

[image: The Transformer Schematic]

Comment: But the model is trained to predict the next step (or steps) via the loss function. Why would we need positional encodings there? That just makes the problem more complex. If the time series is non-uniformly sampled then you could at an additional layer to output the position or whatever and have some kind of combined loss.

Comment: What you suggested here is the best idea I have come up with so far if I really needed to predict the time value of the output, ie represent this time value as a separate value. Also the more I think about it, depending on the task we may not even need to predict this time value. Just thought it was strange that we definitely want to add this positional encoding to the input and not the output. The input is just a uniformly sampled sequence so why is the positional encoding necessary at all?